# Why Am I getting "None" when using ForeignKey on integer value from another model that I know that have integer number?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wanted to ask you for your help. I have two models. In the first one I wanted to reference foriegn key from the second one to be able to print votescore that I store there.

My models.py :

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    votesscore = models.ForeignKey('VoteQuestion', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='question_votesscore')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class VoteQuestion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    votesubmitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    votesscore = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    amountofvotes = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.votesscore

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'question', 'votesscore']
```

Next in my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    allquestionswithanswers = Question.objects.filter(datecompleted__isnull=False)
    allquestionswithoutanswers = Question.objects.filter(datecompleted__isnull=True)
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'allquestionswithanswers': allquestionswithanswers, 'allquestionswithoutanswers': allquestionswithoutanswers})
```

And in my home.html I am calling it like this:

```
{% for question in allquestionswithanswers %}
<li>
    {{ question }} Score: {{ question.votesscore }} {{ question.user }}
    <br><br>

    <form class='my-ajax-form' method='POST' action='' data-url="{% url 'questionvoteup' question.id %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type='submit'>UP</button>
    </form>



    {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
        {{ answer }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And when I try to print `{{ question.votesscore }}` I get value "None". Yet I am sure that in database it is an integer value. Could you please point me in right direction with this ?

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: what is the output of {{ question.votesscore.voterscore }}?

Comment: It's nothing. It is not printing anything on my site.

Comment: check {{allquestionswithanswers}} in templates and see any data is there

Comment: I get <QuerySet [<Question: My first Question?>]>  And that is because I have __str__ method.

Without It I get <QuerySet [<Question: Question object (6)>]>

Comment: also check any data in VoteQustion class

Comment: I also deleted __str__ and I got: <QuerySet [<VoteQuestion: VoteQuestion object (2)>, <VoteQuestion: VoteQuestion object (3)>, <VoteQuestion: VoteQuestion object (1)>]> 

I used VoteQuestion.objects to get that. I am new in python and django so I am not sure If you meant this ?

Comment: delete all the data in both class and create again, since you are learning, do the things again and again until you see some results

Comment: Oh, but can you tell me what I did wrong ? I mean, I spent a lot of time and solved a lot of problems (also asking a lot of question here) to get to this point. So right now I am not aware what I should do different. So if I delete everything right now I will probably end in the same place ?